# What do -webkit-box-shadow and -moz-box-shadow do?

Tags: html, css

I was recently searching online for CSS tricks and came across a box shadow example that went as follows:

```
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 2px 4px black;
-moz-box-shadow:0px 2px 4px black;
box-shadow:0px 2px 4px black;
```

I tested it out and it seems to produce the same result when you only have the box-shadow line of code so I'm just wondering what the purpose of the webkit-box-shadow and moz-box-shadow are?

Comment: That's for older WebKit and Firefox browsers that do not yet officially support the `box-shadow` property. But for now it s very widely supported so the vendor prefixes might not be necessary. You are likely using a recent version that supports the unprefixed property :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [Browser Prefixes](http://css-snippets.com/browser-prefix/), they are used by browsers to experiment and test out new CCS3 implementations before solidifying them in their browser standards.